# Redirect if iOS, Android or Windows Phone

Tags: php, android, ios, redirect

I need a little bit of help here. I need help with a script. I try:

```
<script language=javascript>
<!--
if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) {
    location.replace("http://url-to-send-them/iphone.html");
}
-->
</script>
```

But is not working as I expected. I need to redirect to different stores if I go to one URL example. If i go to: `www.mydomain.com.ar/app` and I use an Android Phone I need to redirect my browser to the Android Play Store. If I go to `www.mydomain.com.ar/app` and I use iOS I need to redirect to the App Store. How can i do this? I dont have the knowledge so if you can help me will be great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
var isMobile = {
    Android: function() {
        return /Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    },
    iOS: function() {
        return /iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
    },
    any: function() {
        return (isMobile.Android() || isMobile.BlackBerry() || isMobile.iOS() || isMobile.Windows());
    }
};
```